# Generic typings for one property on an Interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I'm trying to type a method, that is part of an interface and I need it to take a generic. Below is a simplified example of what I want. I want users of the API be able to
type method with a generic. However I don't know here to specify it.

Can anyone explain to me how to add generics to `method` on Main here? Without the generics being passed to the Main interface but to the actual method.

```
interface Method<T> {
  (t: T): T
}

interface Main {
  method: Method
}

const main: Main = {
  method: id => id,
}

main.method<string>('test')
```

Comment: You need to put the type parameter on the signature https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLITACwPYBNkDeAUMsgDwAqAfABRgBcyFAlIxUQL5FGiSyIpUcUIRLIAthhy5G6LHk7cE2EAGcwE4SFlbkAXlGlJ8mcmD49VM7gA0iouK0A6Y9LLqooAOa0A5JHVfZiA

Comment: Thank you! Can you post this as answer so I can resolve this? haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined a generic type that happens to be a function. What you really want is a generic function. To do that you need to put the generic type list on the signature, not the type

```
interface Method {
  <T>(t: T): T
}

interface Main {
  method: Method
}

const main: Main = {
  method: id => id,
}

main.method<string>('test')
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLITACwPYBNkDeAUMsgDwAqAfABRgBcyFAlIxUQL5FGiSyIpUcUIRLIAthhy5G6LHk7cE2EAGcwE4SFlbkAXlGlJ8mcmD49VM7gA0iouK0A6Y9LLqooAOa0A5JHVfZiA)